# Why '.*[.].*$' matches with filename.extension?

Tags: python, regex

While looking into the regular expression, I found the following example:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('.*[.].*$')
>>> m = p.search('foo.bar')
>>> print(m.group())
foo.bar
```

I don't understand the process in which it recognizes simple filename with extensions like `foo.bar`, `abc.xyz`, `my_files.txt`. I thought this code would work like this:

1. `.` matches with any character.
2. `*` causes to match 0 or more repetitions.
3. By *1.* and *2.*, the **whole string(`foo.bar`) matches with `.*`**.
4. `[.]` tries to find character `.`, but there are **no characters left**.
5. `.*$` doesn't do anything.
6. No matches found.

I wonder how this code actually works.

Comment: By that logic you'd never be able to use `.*` in a regex because it would always match everything, which obviously isn't the case

Comment: `.*` matches `foo` because it backtracks so that `[.]` matches the `.`. The rest of the string is matched by `.*$`. You have to remember that regex engines *want* to match something, so they'll try until all possible tests have been exhausted.

Comment: Use regex101.com to explain it for you: https://regex101.com/r/nYevrx/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `*` causes the regex engine to match *as much as possible,* not *everything.*

Typically, the regex engine will match through the end of line like you describe, but then backtrack to an earlier position until it can proceed with the rest of the match.

Maybe think of it sort of like a labyrinth solver which explores every possible junction of the labyrinth systematically until if finds an exit, or exhausts the search space.

Comment: didn't knew greedy `*` gives characters back as needed.